# Plotting arrows in a map to show shifts in coordinates or points using ggplot2

Tags: point, vector, spatial-analyst, legend, ggplot2

**Plotting arrows in a map to show shifts in coordinates or points using ggplot2**

I have three points in my map (latitudes and longitudes of the points: a, b and c are provided below). I would like to draw arrows of different colors and later show the points and arrows on the legend of my map. The arrow should move from point a to point b (this arrow can be red in color and named first). Another arrow can be drawn from point b to point c (this arrow can be green in color and named second). The points in the map can be of different shapes ie rectangle, triangle etc Point a can be named current, point b named future_1 and point c named future_2

below is my code

## load require libraries

library(maptools)#
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)

#### get the map of the world

data("wrld_simpl")
crs(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl)

#plot africa
africa <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$REGION==2,]
plot(africa)

##change into a format that can be used in ggplot2
AG <- fortify(africa)
crs(africa)
names(AG)

##m points
a <  -1.28333, 36.81667
b <- 3.327709,  6.457171
c <- -17.82772, 31.05337

##plot using ggplot2
ggplot()+ geom_polygon(data=AG, aes(long, lat, group = group), colour = alpha("darkred"), size = 0.8, fill = 'skyblue', alpha = .3)